# Install some packages (with deps) on machine that has no internet connection

Tags: apt, system-installation, package-management, kvm-virtualization

I have server with installed minimal "Ubuntu 14.04. server" on it.
This server has no internet connection.
How can I deliver on this machine packages like qemu-kvm, libvirt-bin, virtinst (with their deps, of course!).
I only can ssh to this server.
Is ubuntu have "everything dvd", like CentOS have, for example?
Or, mb I can buil this dvd/cd by myself?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to import the package from your machine to the server machine and install it.

- Creating you own DVD Repo - [Follow this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=352460)
- Copy all the .deb packages inside your /var/cache/apt/archives folder and scp it to the server. Then in the server install the packages via the following command.
  `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
- Try [Keryx](https://launchpad.net/keryxproject). Its a package manager allows you to download the packages to you pendrive and you can install it in your machine where you don't have an internet connection.

As you have an server machine Keryx won't suit you. You can try the other options.